# Two Methods of Getting an Image from URL: The Differences?

Tags: objective-c, uiimage, nsurlconnection, nsdata

What are the main differences between the following two methods of fetching a UIImage from a URL?  I recently switched **from Method 1** to **Method 2** in my app and seemed to experience a drastic increase in speed when I thought that, essentially, both methods were nearly the same in practice.  Just trying to figure out why I saw such a speed increase.

**Method 1**

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:self.imageURL];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        self.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    });
});
```

---

**Method 2**

```
- (void)fetchImage
{
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:self.imageURL];
    self.imageData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    self.imageURLConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}   

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    if(connection == self.imageURLConnection)
    {
        [self.imageData appendData:data];
    }
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    if(connection == self.imageURLConnection)
    {
        self.image = [UIImage imageWithData:self.imageData];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess is that because for **Method 1** the `AsyncURLConnection` class multithreads:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    /* process downloaded data in Concurrent Queue */

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        /* update UI on Main Thread */
```

So, you may see degraded performance due to contention for shared resources.

On the other hand **Method 2**, is actually just a collection of methods which are implemented more like transaction processing.

There's probably also more to it.

Comment: But isn't Method 2 also using sending an asynchronous request, meaning, it would be multithreaded too?

Comment: The `dispatch_async()` functions schedule blocks for concurrent execution *[1](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/dispatch_async.3.html) .  NSURLConnection in **Method 2** conforms to `NSMutableCopying` so the compiler does any lifting before run time. *[2](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Hmmm that is an interesting theory... +1

Comment: Just a guess.. :/  If you ran a small chunk of the program in a multi-core environment, I wonder if the difference would be less drastic then?